# What are the words used with "a pair of"?

Tags: word-request

I have gathered the following:

> a pair of socks/ stockings/ gloves/ earrings/ shoes/ sneakers(trainers)/ slippers/ sandals/ skis

and

> a pair of jeans/ trousers/ pants/ glasses/spectacles/ binoculars/ goggles/ scissors/ tweezers/ shoes/ boots/ tights

I would like to have a complete list of words accompanied by *a pair of*. I could not find it via internet search. A link containing such a list will be truly appreciated.

Comment: Can you think of nouns that **cannot** be used with 'a pair of'? Sure, some may sound odd, but if they just happen to come in pairs, then you can just as well have 'a pair of tulips' and 'a pair of evil masterminds'. The possibilities are endless!

Answer (score 3):

Check this [definition](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search1?word=pair) (1). You don't need a long list. You just need to learn the premise of using "a pair of".
Start with the idea "two of the same", learn a few collocations (like the ones you suggest above), and proceed from there.

> A pair of socks
>   [image: Pair of socks!]

is nice and easy because there are two of them!

> A pair of pliers
>   [image: Pair of pliers!]

is a little more difficult because there is one object, so why a pair? Wait! Look closer; there are two objects exactly the same that are attached! Hence, a pair of pliers, a pair of scissors etc.